# Removing special characters using Ruby, but not spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

I was looking for awhile on here and didn't quite find what I needed. I am learning Ruby(1.9) and am trying to do something basic with a text file. I am trying to use RegEx's to remove non-letters, and white space that is ONLY at the beginning of the line, ignoring spaces between tokens(I am trying to count words in the file, hence when I want the spaces between words to remain).

Ex:

```
555 r6ub6y i7s e7a0sy... w1o2w4.
```

To change to:

```
ruby is easy... wow.
```

What I have so far using the command-line to test `ruby rubyfile.rb < test.txt`:

```
$stdin.each do |line|
    line.chomp!.downcase!
    line.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "") #this takes away my spaces!
    puts line
end
```

Comment: Note that `chomp!` will return `nil` if no changes are made. It's somewhat unexpected behavior

Comment: @JKillian "unexpected" or "undesirable" in this case. The bang(!) methods for strings often return nil when changes are not applied. Bang implies a more dangerous mutation of it's like named method sometimes it alters the receiver or in some way produces results that differ from the non-bang method. I see it as ! Means danger expect something different.

Comment: @engineersmnky Aye, I'm familiar with bang methods, and you're absolutely correct that many for strings behave similarly to `chomp`. I just personally find it strange that in general they can't be chained like the regular versions...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z. ]
```

add a space as well.

Comment: E.g., `text.each_line { |l| puts l.downcase.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z ]/,'').strip }`.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `A-Z` part because you've already downcased it.

Comment: @MarkThomas just used the OP's regex.

Comment: An important detail is the use of `strip` instead of `chomp` since it removes leading whitespace as well.

Comment: @vks simply updating the regex is not a complete answer, as Cary and I are pointing out.

Comment: no one mentioned that this will also remove the periods which is not the intended result.

Answer (score 5):

Since right now you are only specifying the removal of numbers this will work as a single line.

```
"555 r6ub6y i7s e7a0sy... w1o2w4.".gsub(/\d/,'').strip 
#=>"ruby is easy... wow."
```

It basically says remove all the numbers and the leading/trailing whitespace.

Right now your regex says remove everything but upper and lower case letters. Not sure what other types of characters you wanted removed but something like this might work for you too if you only wanted upper/lowercase letters spaces and periods

```
"555 r6ub6y i7s e7a0sy... w1o2w4.".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s.]/,'').strip 
#=>"ruby is easy... wow."
```

Also when including spaces in a regex I always tend to use `\s` instead of an implied space like `[ ]` because I feel it adds to readability as `[a-zA-Z ]` might be a typo and should not include spaces but `[a-zA-Z\s]` is very definitive in saying I want spaces.

Want to Learn more about Regex check out [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) it is a regular expression evaluator for Ruby and I use it all the time. The only thing it doesn't really discuss on it's own is greedy and non-greedy capture groups but I have a feeling you don't have to worry about this right now.